Several conditions for searching with an operator OR
Need to make search by post_type = 'specialist' OR post_parent = '49888'
When using "post_parent", "post_type" is "page", so may be
post_type = 'specialist' OR (post_parent = '49888' AND post_type = 'page')
This code at functions.php working only with last $query->set , how to combine them through OR?
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() )
    {
        $query->set("post_type", "specialist");
        $query->set( "post_parent", "49888" );
    }
});


I don't think you can do that via $query->set. You will have to look into how to modify the resulting SQL statement using the relevant hook.

First post type should be hierarchical like page and then you can set post_parent. If post_parent is different post type you cant mix like that.

One way to do this is by using the posts_where filter to directly manipulate the SQL query.
Try this:
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search()) {
        $query->set('my_custom_condition', true);
    }
});

add_filter('posts_where', function($where, $query) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ($query->get('my_custom_condition')) {
        $where .= " AND ({$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'specialist' OR ({$wpdb->posts}.post_parent = 49888 AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'page'))";
    }

    return $where;
}, 10, 2);

